# Invalidating the control while changing parameters in the collection editor

Tags: .net, custom-controls, collectioneditor

We are looking for a more elegant way to update control contents while editing it's properties in a collection editor.

As far as we know the only solution is the following: http://dotnetfacts.blogspot.com/2008/05/how-to-take-control-over-collection.html

And therefore declaring a static event handler:

```
public static event MyPropertyValueChangedEventHandler MyPropertyValueChanged
```

This solution has a number of drawbacks (think about having more than one control) and we were wondering if a different approach is possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the most useful link found so far: http://engineeringdotnet.blogspot.com/2010/08/modifying-c-collectioneditor-for-real.html